# getting rid of last comma

Tags: java

I need help getting rid of the last comma when my program prints out the integers 5 through 1

```
int i;

for (i=10; i>1; --i){
    if ( i%2==0) {
        System.out.print( i/2 + "," );
```

It prints out `5,4,3,2,1,`

I want it to print out `5,4,3,2,1`

Comment: Why don't you store the string you are building by printing in a variable and then print that variable's substring with a length one less than the variable?

Comment: Try to use a StringBuilder to create your string and then at the end just remove the last character of you stringbuilder

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way is as following:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (i=10; i>1; --i){
    if ( i%2==0) {
       stringBuilder.append(i/2);
       stringBuilder.append(",");
    }
}
stringBuilder.setLength(stringBuilder.length()-1);//remove last comma
System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple if will do it like this but **better and more efficient** approach is to use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```
int i = 0;
        for (i = 10; i > 1; --i) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(i / 2);
                if (i > 2) {
                    System.out.print(",");
                }

            }
        }
```

With StringBuilder the code will look like this

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (i = 10; i > 1; --i) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            sb.append(i / 2).append(",");
        }
    }
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(sb);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several differnt ways, e.g. write to a buffer an strip the last comma before printing it, or an additional if condition saying if i == 2 System.out.print( i/2);

Answer (score 0):

Here is my general purpose solution utilizing the StringBuilder class:

```
/**
 * @param x Inclusive from-value
 * @param y Inclusive to-value
 * @param step Gap between numbers
 * @param separator What separates the numbers from each other?
 * @return Numbers from x to y separated by a separator in String format
 */
public static String integersFromXToYWithSeparator(Integer x, Integer y,Integer step, Character separator) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Integer localStep = Math.abs(step);
    if (x < y) {
        while (x <= y) {
            builder.append(x);
            builder.append(separator);
            x+=localStep;
        }
    } else  if (x > y) {
        while (x >= y) {
            builder.append(x);
            builder.append(separator);
            x-=localStep;
        }
    }
    builder.setLength(builder.length()-1);
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `java-8` there is a [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class which helps to solve this problem:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
for (int i = 10; i > 1; --i) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        joiner.add(String.valueOf(i / 2));
    }
}
System.out.println(joiner.toString());
```

or using `stream - api`

```
String result =
        IntStream.iterate(10, i -> i - 1)
                .limit(10).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                .map(i -> i / 2)
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

System.out.println(result);
```